# ANDing two List<Long> Object in Java

Tags: java

I want to perform ANDing operation between two `List<Long>` Java Objects. Lets say I have

```
List<Long> groupBits1 = Arrays.asList(new Long[]{Long.valueOf(1L), Long.valueOf(0L), Long.valueOf(0L), Long.valueOf(0L), Long.valueOf(0L)});

List<Long> groupBits2 = Arrays.asList(new Long[]{Long.valueOf(2L), Long.valueOf(1L), Long.valueOf(0L), Long.valueOf(0L), Long.valueOf(0L)});
```

Now is there a way Java list can perform ANDing between the two without individually ANDing on index?

e.g. something like

```
List<Long> groupBits3 = groupBits1 & groupBits2;
```

and groupBits3 will have following bits

`groupBits1.get(0) &  groupBits2.get(0), groupBits1.get(1) &  groupBits2.get(1),` ... and so on

Comment: what is the question?? pl explain more

Comment: please add more information on what you want to process

Comment: what exactly you mean by Anding i.e. creating third list with elements form both the list or item1 from list 1 boolean AND item1 from list 2?

Comment: Yes exactly. Will add to description.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do it is to iterate through both list and perform a bitwise and between each pair. This can be done with a loop.

```
List<Long> listAnd = new ArrayList<>(groupBits1.size());
for(int i = 0; i < groupBits1.size(); i++) {
    listAnd.add(groupBits1.get(i) & groupBits2.get(i));
}
```

With [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) you could use the new Stream API to do this in a one-liner.

```
List<Long> listAnd = IntStream.range(0, groupBits1.size())
                .mapToObj(x -> groupBits1.get(x) & groupBits2.get(x))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Since `Arrays.asList` returns a fixed-size ArrayList, `get` is a O(1) operation so there won't be a performance problem.

Also note that `Arrays.asList` can take a varargs argument as parameter. Since Java automatically box your primitives to objects if required (since Java 5), you could simply do:

```
List<Long> groupBits1 = Arrays.asList(1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L);
List<Long> groupBits2 = Arrays.asList(2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
groupBits1.retainAll(groupBits2)
```

[Every List implements the set interface.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html)

> s1.containsAll(s2) — returns true if s2 is a subset of s1. (s2 is a subset of s1 if set s1 contains all of the elements in s2.)
>
> s1.addAll(s2) — transforms s1 into the union of s1 and s2. (The union of two sets is the set containing all of the elements contained in either set.)
>
> s1.retainAll(s2) — transforms s1 into the intersection of s1 and s2. (The intersection of two sets is the set containing only the elements common to both sets.)
>
> s1.removeAll(s2) — transforms s1 into the (asymmetric) set difference of s1 and s2. (For example, the set difference of s1 minus s2 is the set containing all of the elements found in s1 but not in s2.)

Comment: I doubt that retailAll can do what I intended :(. It performs an intersection instead a Boolean AND.

Comment: You can use java 8 and lambdas. Look at ZouZou's answer.